# Why scrapy is not returning any links?

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy, web-crawler

Recently, I tried to make some tool to ease myself an apartment search and get only relevant information as soon as possible (the site is not so user-friendly), but I've run into a problem and maybe I'm just home-blind at the moment...or just plain stupid as this is not quite my expertise.

So, anyway. I have a link with filtered out results:

```
class BostadSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bostadformedlingen"
    start_urls = ['https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/?s=58.66266&n=59.99899&w=17.07550&e=19.23431&sort=annonserad-fran-desc']

    def parse(self, response):
        for ad in response.css(
            "div.apartment-search-hits > ul.apartment-search-ad-list > li.ad-list__item > a::attr('href')"):
        print(ad.get())
```

And this is structure from website:

```
<main class="display-flex flex-column search-wrapper u-m-a-0 u-p-a-0" id="main-content">
    <div class="row no-gutters search-wrapper__inner">
        <div id="apartment-search-hits" class="apartment-search-hits" aria-hidden="false">
            <ul id="apartment-search-ad-list" class="ad-list" aria-hidden="false">
                <li class="ad-list__item"> <a href="/Lista/Details?aid=190412" class="ad-list__link">
```

Should I go "a bit more up" and include "main"?

Comment: And I tried including step by step parents but...no luck!

Comment: I changed the variable "url" to "start_urls" (beginner's mistake), but still response now is `[protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 24 without any user agent to enforce it on.` (and on line 26, 27, 31, 38...)

Comment: `DEBUG: Crawled (404)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually data is generating from api calls json response. If you make disable javascript then you will see that page go blank meaning the url is dynamic. That's why we can't get data thus way. Here is the working solution:

CODE:

```
import scrapy
import json

class BostSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'bost'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser',
            method='GET',
            callback=self.parse)
       

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = json.loads(response.body)
        
        for h in resp:
            url = h['Url']
            abs_url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield {
                'URL': abs_url
            }
```

Output:

```
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190400'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190401'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190360'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190325'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190413'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190412'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190383'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190229'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190230'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190414'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190407'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190432'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190377'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190424'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190291'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190382'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190384'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190356'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190349'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190287'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190399'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190428'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190404'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190368'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190371'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190373'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190390'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190385'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190416'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190396'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190394'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190402'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190359'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190358'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190357'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190265'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190264'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190422'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190420'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190410'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190398'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190429'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190403'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190423'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190417'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190362'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190361'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190387'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190376'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190386'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190391'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190369'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190363'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190409'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190427'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190364'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190378'}
2021-09-20 05:43:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser>  
{'URL': 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/Details?aid=190375'}
```

... so on

Comment: Ah... Solution is brilliant but damn JSON response in 'https://bostad.stockholm.se/Lista/AllaAnnonser' is actually not returning all available ads. I just realized that it is missing 40% of ads. And within ads returned in response it is missing 50% of information like rent, number of rooms (while for sure there is that information available). Didn't saw that coming :(

Comment: Maybe I could find link to generate dynamic link and then use it as start_urls?

Comment: how it is possible that AllaAnnonser doesn't hold all the links

Comment: would it be possible to generate link instead?

Comment: To grab all links, you have to make pagination. I think you , You are familiar with pagination as a scrapy user.

Comment: or please,  ask an another question indicating  that portion